# POCO navigation property not updating when foreign key is assigned a value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a POCO class (`OPERATION`) that is used as an Entity Framework entity. This class has a navigation property (`OP`) and a foreign key into the same related entity (`OP_ID`).

In a method, I get an `OPERATION` and on this `OPERATION` the `OP_ID` and `OP` are both `null`. When I set the `OP_ID` to a valid value for this foreign key, the `OP` navigation property remains `null`. When I explicitly detect changes in the context, the `OP` navigation property is now assigned with the correct value.

**Sample code**

```
public bool UpdateOperation(operationID)
{
    IQueryable<OPERATION> operations = from o in base.ctx.OPERATION
                                                        select o;

    OPERATION operation = operations
        .Where(o => o.OPERATION_ID == operationID)
        .Include("OP")
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (operation != null)
    {
        operation.OP_ID = opId;
    }
    
    // operation.OP is null here

    operation.GetContext().ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    // operation.OP is populated here
}
```

I have confirmed that the `operation` is, in fact, a dynamic proxy. For what it's worth, once I detect changes, `operation.OP` also becomes a dynamic proxy. However, even then, assigning a *different* value to `operation.OP_ID` still requires an explicit `DetectChanges()` call in order to update the value of `operation.OP`.

**Update**

In response to the comment from @ErikPhilips, the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships?redirectedfrom=MSDN) seems to imply that this *should* happen. Specifically:

> The following examples show how to use the foreign key properties and navigation properties to associate the related objects. With foreign key associations, you can use either method to change, create, or modify relationships. With independent associations, you cannot use the foreign key property.
>
> By assigning a new value to a foreign key property, as in the following example.
>
> `course.DepartmentID = newCourse.DepartmentID;`
>
> ...
>
> When you change the relationship of the objects attached to the context by using one of the methods described above, Entity Framework needs to keep foreign keys, references, and collections in sync. Entity Framework automatically manages this synchronization (also known as relationship fix-up) for the POCO entities with proxies.
>
> If you are using POCO entities without proxies, you must make sure that the DetectChanges method is called to synchronize the related objects in the context.

Some additional context may be useful, as well. This is a legacy application that used to work directly with an `ObjectContext` instead of a `DbContext`, though even then using EF 6. We are now migrating to the `DbContext` API. This particular code, without any modifications, used to demonstrate the behavior I'm expecting. Specifically, when `OP_ID` is assigned, I can see in the debugger that the `OP` property is automatically populated to point to the correct `OPERATION`.

Comment: Why would it automatically do that? No documentation anywhere states that happens or should happen.  It's probably best it doesn't happen because loading an object just because a value changes could be detrimental to performance if it was done to many objects (as each object will be a single call to the DB).

Comment: Great question, @ErikPhilips. I've added some additional detail to my question that I hope answers it for you.

Comment: We can see from their own documentation that *changing* a foreign key requires one to call `.Load()`.  [Loading related object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships?redirectedfrom=MSDN#loading-related-objects)

Comment: While the documentation is poor on fixups (object syncronization), from my experience fixups only happen if the object is already loaded in memory (proxy or not), OR you're accessing a navigation property who's primary key *has not changed* on a proxy object.

Comment: To your last point, if I call `DetectChanges()` (so that the object is loaded in memory) and then change the foreign key *again*, I have to call `DetectChanges()` ***again*** for the navigation property to update the second time.

About the documentation, contrary to your first comment, the documentation very clearly states that "by assigning a new value to a foreign key property...Entity Framework automatically manages this synchronization." :) What's entirely confusing to me is *how this worked when I was working with an `ObjectContext` directly*.

Comment: Overall, since it ***did*** work previously, I am led to believe that there's something amiss with how my classes are wired up, properties are declared/decorated, etc. Can you suggest something I should check with respect to this?

Comment: Post *all related code*.  IE, you're poco's and your context.  Secondly your exact quote is **not** what you're doing.  You are **not** changing a navigation property, you are changing the navigation foreign key.  The documentation **clearly states** *By assigning a new **object** to a **navigation property**... the corresponding **foreign key property** on the course object is set to the **key property** value of the department*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I *was* doing exactly what the documentation described. I was

> assigning a new value to a foreign key property.

Yes, Entity Framework does manage this in fix-up. And yes, the documentation does state this.

It turns out, though, that the egg is ultimately on my face. I had checked the classes generated from my T4 template, and seen that all navigation properties *were* marked `virtual`. I had not checked thoroughly enough to note that the foreign key properties *were not* marked `virtual`, however. It appears that this is the default behavior of the EF-provided T4 template used when working model- or database-first. I've addressed this by changing this line in the `CodeStringGenerator.Property()` method in the T4 template

```
Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty)
```

to

```
AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty))
```

In the end, as usual, following the documentation (here, the requirements for EF change tracking on POCOs) often results in dependent code behaving as it is documented. Shame on me.